# Hyperlinks do not work on left mouse click

Tags: html, hyperlink

So, the funniest thing happened, which is completely new to me...

In my Joomla website I have these articles with external links in 'em. Wherever I place these articles inside modules, all is fine. However, inside the component area they don't work. You can hover over them and see the link apearing. Right click and 'open in new window' works. But, left click does nothing.

Tried everything I could think of for over hours. Anyone any ideas?
Here is the link to the page. Try clicking on the icons "youtube", "facebook", or "external link".

https://kongress.drisoto.com/live

I checked for any errors in the console. Switch nearly all plugins on and off. Switched php-versions, and so on.
Joomla and all addons are up to date. Php 7.1.

Left mouse click should just open the links in a new window. Why doesn't it?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined an event handler that ignores all clicks inside your `#sp-main-body`.

In your theme/itilco/scroll.js you have this:

```
/**
 * @package Helix Framework
 * @author JoomShaper http://www.joomshaper.com
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010 - 2013 JoomShaper
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPLv2 or later
*/

jQuery(function($){
    var $body = $('body'),
    $wrapper = $('.body-innerwrapper'),
    $toggler = $('#offcanvas-toggler'),
    $close = $('#sp-main-body'),
    $offCanvas = $('.offcanvas-menu');


    $close.on('click', function(event){
        /* #### issue is here ### */
        event.preventDefault();
        offCanvasClose();
    });
```

There's an event handler preventing the browser from handling the default action of the click opening the link.

Comment: You are a lifesaver...
I would have never found this.
Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

@Contentiteit,

Try updating `<a>` to the following. Note the `onclick` attribute added.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/AnneHeintzeLife" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/AnneHeintzeLife')">
<!--img tag here-->
</a>
```

As correctly [identified by Slawomir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56076302/11480716), JavaScript is preventing the default behavior when you click on the links.

Comment: Thanx a million!